# How to Generate all the characters in the UTF-8 charset in .net

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, character-encoding

I have been given the task of generating all the characters in the UTF-8 character set to test how a system handles each of them.   I do not have much experience with character encoding.  The approaching I was going to try was to increment a counter, and then try to translate that base ten number into it's equivalent UTF-8 character, but so far I have no been able to find an effective way to to this in C# 3.5

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are 1,112,064 code points in the Unicode standard.  Do you really want to generate all of them?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this clarifies things greatly.  To better explain my task,  I am testing a service that seems to be choking on some Chinese characters.  So it was decided that we should be able to test all foreign characters since the system will need to be able to handle a variety of international languages.

I am looking for a simple and effective solution that wont take long to create and has maximum coverage.

Comment: @DanielPryden 1,112,064 isn't a very large number for  a computer.  If it takes 100 cycles to generate one, a 3GHz computer would take 0.037 seconds to go through them all.

Answer (score 8):

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string definedCodePoints = client.DownloadString(
                         "http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt");
System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(definedCodePoints);
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
while(true) {
  string line = reader.ReadLine();
  if(line == null) break;
  int codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";")), 16);
  if(codePoint >= 0xD800 && codePoint <= 0xDFFF) {
    //surrogate boundary; not valid codePoint, but listed in the document
  } else {
    string utf16 = char.ConvertFromUtf32(codePoint);
    byte[] utf8 = encoder.GetBytes(utf16);
    //TODO: something with the UTF-8-encoded character
  }
}
```

The above code should iterate over the currently assigned Unicode characters. You'll probably want to parse the [UnicodeData](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) file locally and fix any C# blunders I've made.

The set of currently assigned Unicode characters is less than the set that could be defined. Of course, whether you see a character when you print one of them out depends on a great many other factors, like fonts and the other applications it'll pass through before it is emitted to your eyeball.

Answer (score 7):

There is no "UTF-8 characters". Do you mean Unicode characters or UTF-8 encoding of Unicode characters?

It's easy to convert an int to a Unicode character, provided of course that there is a mapping for that code:

```
char c = (char)theNumber;
```

If you want the UTF-8 encoding for that character, that's not very hard either:

```
byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.ToString())
```

You would have to check the Unicode standard to see the number ranges where there are Unicode characters defined.

Answer (score 5):

Even once you generate all the characters, you'll find it's not an effective test. Some of the characters are *combining* marks, which means they will combine with the next character to come after them - having a string full of combining marks won't make much sense. There are other special cases too.  You'll be much better off using actual text in the languages you need to support.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 isn't a character *set* - it's a character *encoding* which is capable of encoding any character in the Unicode character set into binary data.

Could you give more information about what you're trying to do? You could encode all the possible Unicode characters (including ones which aren't allocated at the moment) although if you need to cope with characters outside the basic multilingual plane (i.e. those above U+FFFF) then it becomes slightly trickier...

Answer (score 2):

You can brute-force an `Encoding` to figure out which code points it supports. To do so, simply go through all possible code points, convert them to strings, and see if `Encoding.GetBytes()` throws an exception or not (after setting `Encoding.EncoderFallback` to `EncoderExceptionFallback`).

```
IEnumerable<int> GetAllWritableCodepoints(Encoding encoding)
{
    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding.WebName, new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());

    var i = -1;
    // Docs for char.ConvertFromUtf32() say that 0x10ffff is the maximum code point value.
    while (i != 0x10ffff)
    {
        i++;

        var success = false;
        try
        {
            encoding.GetByteCount(char.ConvertFromUtf32(i));
            success = true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
        }
        if (success)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This method should support discovering characters represented by surrogate pairs of `Char` in .net. However, it is very slow (takes minutes to run on my machine) and probably impractical.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is not a charset, it's an encoding.
Any value in Unicode can be encoded in UTF-8 with different byte lengths.

For .net, the characters are 16-bit (it's not the complete set of unicode but is the most practical), so you can try this:

```
 for (char i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
     string s = "" + i;
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
     // do something with bytes
 }
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but your second paragraph is misleading.  `System.Char` is a 16-bit value, true.  But MSDN makes it clear that a `System.Char` is a UTF-16 code point, which means that it is not technically a character.  There are plenty of Unicode characters that can be represented in UTF-8 that have code points above 65536.  You say "it's not the complete set of unicode it is the most practical" -- I'm not certain that's true, and it's certainly not a good reason to avoid testing code points above U+FFFF.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the characters in a charset - just make sure you specify a charset when specifying the Encoding:

```
var results = new ConcurrentBag<int> ();
Parallel.For (0, 10, set => {
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding ("ISO-8859-1");
    var c = encoding.GetEncoder ();
    c.Fallback = new EncoderExceptionFallback ();
    var start = set * 1000;
    var end = start + 1000;
    Console.WriteLine ("Worker #{0}: {1} - {2}", set, start, end);

    char[] input = new char[1];
    byte[] output = new byte[5];
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        try {
            input[0] = (char)i;
            c.GetBytes (input, 0, 1, output, 0, true);
            results.Add (i);
        }
        catch {
        }
    }
});
var hashSet = new HashSet<int> (results);
//hashSet.Remove ((int)'\r');
//hashSet.Remove ((int)'\n');
var sorted = hashSet.ToArray ();
Array.Sort (sorted);
var charset = new string (sorted.Select (i => (char)i).ToArray ());
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will produce the output in a file. All characters printable or not will be in there.

```
Encoding enc = (Encoding)Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").Clone();
enc.EncoderFallback = new EncoderReplacementFallback("");
char[] chars = new char[1];
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\utf-8.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        chars[0] = (char)i;
        int count = enc.GetBytes(chars, 0, 1, bytes, 0);

        if (count != 0)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(chars[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Didn't even have to open VS. I compiled the code with a script. It began to work instantly, immediately and accurately, well, almost like straight "out of the box"

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, UTF / Unicode is an encoding not a character set.

If you skim though http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html it should help clarify what unicode is.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell code with which, I put together the lines which I made by the code suggested by Jake into a text file with 256 lines length.

Service symbols create two blank lines that do not exist in the original, which must be removed in the original text file befor Powershell processing in order for the resulting file to be created correctly.

I'll just post here what the ASC2 part should look like.

NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US Space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~  PAD HOP BPH NBH IND NEL SSA ESA HTS HTJ VTS PLD PLU RI SS2 SS3 DCS PU1 PU2 STS CCH MW SPA EPA SOS SGCI SCI CSI ST OSC PM APC Non-breakingSpace ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ

In the initial file, each character will be on a new line.

It is better to use Notepad ++ to see the service symbols. It is better to replace them with text with your hands.

Two more service symbols are contained, just below asc2 part and at the end - a lot.

But, to admire the colored emoticons, you can simply copy your favorite text into Word or social network. Word interprets characters better than notepad, but worse than a website.

```
$arrayFromFile = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines('C:\utf-8.txt')
$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
$groupSize = 256
$text=''
$groups = $arrayFromFile | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize) }
foreach ($group in $groups){
    $text+=$group.Group -join (' ')
    $text+="`n"
}
$text | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\utf-8 (sorted).txt'
```