# Where I can get A-Z Unicode character with there values?

Tags: html, xml, unicode

I want the list of complete A-Z Unicode character values like Symbols, Greek, Chains, Japanese, etc…, So where I can get it?

Please share your staff here.

Note:

I want download that Unicode to my local drive, I want form database reference for the complete Unicode with there values (HTML-code)

Comment: I saw http://unicode-table.com/en/ website here more or less all Unicode available but i want to download every thing to my local drive.

Comment: Is there is any way to generate Unicode by programmatically using C#, VB so on?

Comment: A-Z is only 26 letters and does not contain Japanese or any of the other stuff... :-3

Comment: What do you mean by “A-Z Unicode character values”, and what kind of a list you need? What “HTML-code” are you referring to?

Comment: Oh oh sorry for confusion, A-Z means here I want to explain my approach A-Z means everything, All kind of Unicode

Comment: @jukka-k-korpela HTML-code mean let consider eg: "Latin capital letter a with acute" [Á] for this Unicode number: U+00C1, HTML-code: &#193;

Comment: You have the table built into the Operating System of your computer already. There are about 60000 possible characters. You can use any one (assuming you have installed appropriate support in the Control Panels) and inspect if from any point of view that is important for you. Check e.g. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668571/how-to-generate-all-the-characters-in-the-utf-8-charset-in-net

Answer (score 1):

The complete Unicode chart of all characters can be found at the Unicode website: http://www.unicode.org/ucd/

Information about HTML character references can be found at the W3C: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

The official list of named character entities for HTML5 is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references
Anything not found in that list will have to be represented by a numeric character reference, which is derived from the character's Unicode code point (i.e. you don't need a table for that).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you use windows (your avatar, huh?).

Do you tried `charmap.exe`? Just <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open "Run..." and enter `charmap`.

Make sure, you have choosen the right font, you want to use.

Comment: Ya that’s I know, but I want complete list of Unicode in a file, is there is available? That only here I am coming to ask.