# Which double quote characters are automatically replaced when converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-15?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, utf-8, iso-8859-15

I have an input file that is UTF-8 encoded. I need to use some of its content and create an ISO-8859-15 encoded CSV file from it.

The problem is that UTF-8 seems to have several characters for double quotes that are automatically replaced to the character `"` (= [Quotation Mark U+0022](http://unicode-table.com/en/0022/)) when writing the CSV file to the disc.

The ones we found are:

- [Left Double Quotation Mark U+201C](http://unicode-table.com/en/201D/)
- [Right Double Quotation Mark U+201D](http://unicode-table.com/en/201C/)
- [Double Low-9 Quotation Mark U+201E](http://unicode-table.com/en/201E/)
- [Modifier Letter Double Prime U+02BA](http://unicode-table.com/en/02BA/)
- [Combining Double Vertical Line Above U+030E](http://unicode-table.com/en/030E/)
- [Fullwidth Quotation Mark U+FF02](http://unicode-table.com/en/FF02/)

The conversion happens automatically when I write to the CSV file like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(workDir + "/files/vehicles.csv", append: false, encoding: Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15")))
{
    foreach (ad vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(convertVehicleToCsv(vehicle));
    }
}
```

The method `convertVehicleToCsv` escapes double quotes and other special characters of the data, but does not escape the special UTF-8 double quote characters. Now that the double quotes are replaced automatically the CSV is no longer [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) conform and therefore corrupt. Reading it using our CSV library fails.

So the question is:

What other UTF-8 characters are automatically replaced/converted to the "normal" `"` character when converting to ISO-8859-15? Is this documented somewhere? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Out of interest, what would you *expect* to happen in that situation? I assume that ISO-8859-15 just doesn't include those characters.

Comment: Well, I like it that they are replaced this way. But I need to know which characters are "automagically" handled like this.

Comment: It sounds like you should probably just convert the original content to ISO-8859-15 as early as possible, so that the conversion happens *before* escaping. Would that solve it without having to be exhaustive about the replacements? You could find a good chunk of the replacements naively by just converting a string with every Unicode character in... but I don't know whether the encoder might be very smart with multiple characters in some cases..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, here's the list of Unicode code points which .NET is mapping to U+0022 (what you've referred to as "normal double quote" symbol) when using a `StreamWriter` as you've done:

- U+0022
- U+02BA
- U+030E
- U+201C
- U+201D
- U+201E
- U+FF02

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670587/399576), I wrote something quickly which creates a reverse mapping of UTF-8 to ISO-8859-15 (Latin-9).

```
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding latin9 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15");
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

var map = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// same code to get each line from the file as per the linked answer

while (true)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) break;
    string codePointHexAsString = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";"));
    int codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(codePointHexAsString, 16);

    // skip Unicode surrogate area
    if (codePoint >= 0xD800 && codePoint <= 0xDFFF)
        continue;

    string utf16String = char.ConvertFromUtf32(codePoint);
    byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(utf16String);
    byte[] latin9Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, latin9, utf8Bytes);
    string latin9String = latin9.GetString(latin9Bytes);
    byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utf8Bytes);
    string isoString = iso.GetString(isoBytes); // this is not always the same as latin9String!

   string latin9HexAsString = latin9[0].ToString("X");

    if (!map.ContainsKey(latin9HexAsString))
    {
        isoMap[latin9HexAsString] = new List<string>();
    }
    isoMap[latin9HexAsString].Add(codePointHexAsString);
}
```

Interestingly, ISO-8859-15 seems to be replacing more characters than ISO-8859-1, which I didn't expect.

Comment: It would make sense to use ISO-8859-1 as a fallback for ISO-8859-15, since ISO-8859-15 is the same but the international currency symbol is replaced by the Euro (€) symbol. I'm waiting for your updated answer. What is codePoint in your code?

Comment: Your list of characters doesn't include mine, right? I update my question with your entries.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly that's not entirely correct. There's a few more differences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15#Differences_from_ISO-8859-1. In the linked question `codePoint` is an `int` representing the Unicode character code point. PS: my figuring out where in the innards of the framework this conversion is happening won't change the list of characters already given as answer to your question :)

Comment: Looks like that our lis is complete. I added `if (latin9String == "\"") { System.Console.WriteLine(codePoint.ToString("X")); }` to your loop and it printed the codes from my question / your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework uses [best-fit mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx#Anchor_3) by default when converting from Unicode to legacy character encodings, such as ISO-8859-15. This is documented in the [Windows Protocols Unicode Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248954.aspx) on MSDN. That document refers to a download called "Sorting Weight Tables" from the Microsoft Download Center, which include best-fit mappings for the legacy encodings supported by Windows (in the file "Windows Supported Code Page Data Files.zip", at the time of this writing).