# How to Determine Unicode Characters from a UTF-16 String?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, character-encoding, utf-16

I have string that contains an odd Unicode space character, but I'm not sure what character that is. I understand that in C# a string in memory is encoded using the UTF-16 format. What is a good way to determine which Unicode characters make up the string?

This question was marked as a possible duplicate to 
[Determine a string's encoding in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp)
It's not a duplicate of this question because I'm not asking about what the encoding is. I already know that a string in C# is encoded as UTF-16. I'm just asking for an easy way to determine what the Unicode values are in the string.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you concerned about the characters which might be surrogate pairs? If everything's in the BMP, you can just use `foreach (char c in text) { Console.WriteLine((int) c); }`

Comment: Use Char.IsHighSurrogate and Char.IsLowSurrogate if you're not sure.

Comment: What type of characters are not represented by the BMP?

Comment: Try [Character Classes in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note the _General Categories_ and _Named Blocks_.

Comment: svar.ToCharArray() in a quick watch expression is a good way, especially when you change the display format to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

The BMP characters are up to 2 bytes in length (values 0x0000-0xffff), so there's a good bit of coverage there. Characters from the Chinese, Thai, even Mongolian alphabets are there, so if you're not an encoding expert, you might be forgiven if your code only handles BMP characters. But all the same, characters like present here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10330/index.htm  won't be correctly handled by code that assumes it'll fit into two bytes.

Comment: The days you can get away with just the BMP have been gone for a while. A popular class of characters outside the BMP are emoji ☹️.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode seems to identify characters as numeric code points. Not all code points actually refer to characters, however, because Unicode has the concept of [combining characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668639/429091) (which I don’t know much about). However, each Unicode string, even some invalid ones (e.g., illegal sequence of combining characters), can be thought of as a list of code points (numbers).

In the UTF-16 encoding, each code point is encoded as a 2 or 4 byte sequence. In .net, `Char` might roughly correspond to either a 2 byte UTF-16 sequence or half of a 4 byte UTF-16 sequence. When `Char` contains half of a 4 byte sequence, it is considered a “surrogate” because it only has meaning when combined with another `Char` which it must be kept with. To get started with inspecting your .net string, you can get .net to tell you the code points contained in the string, automatically combining surrogate pairs together if necessary. .net provides [`Char.ConvertToUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is described the following way:

> Converts the value of a UTF-16 encoded character or surrogate pair at a specified position in a string into a Unicode code point.

The [documentation for `Char.ConvertToUtf32(String s, Int32 index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that an `ArgumentException` is thrown for the following case:

> The specified index position contains a surrogate pair, and either the first character in the pair is not a valid high surrogate or the second character in the pair is not a valid low surrogate.

Thus, you can go character by character in a string and find all of the Unicode code points with the help of [`Char.IsHighSurrogate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcwwfbb8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Char.ConvertToUtf32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When you don’t encounter a high surrogate, the current character fits in one `Char` and you only need to advance one `Char` in your string. If you do encounter a high surrogate, the character requires two `Char` and you need to advance by two:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetCodePoints(string s)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += char.IsHighSurrogate(s[i]) ? 2 : 1)
    {
        yield return char.ConvertToUtf32(s, i);
    }
}
```

When you say “from a UTF-16 String”, that might imply that you have read in a series of bytes formatted as UTF-16. If that is the case, you would need to convert that to a .net string before passing to the above method:

```
GetCodePoints(Encoding.UTF16.GetString(myUtf16Blob));
```

Another note: depending on how you build your `String` instance, it is possible that it contains an illegal sequence of `Char` with regards to surrogate pairs. For such strings, `Char.ConvertToUtf32()` will throw an exception when encountered. However, I think that `Encoding.GetString()` will always either return a valid string or throw an exception. So, generally, as long as your `String` instances are from “good” sources, you needn’t worry about `Char.ConvertToUtf32()` throwing (unless you pass in random values for the index offset because your offset might be in the middle of a surrogate pair).